# open pdf file through URL using uid

Tags: pdf, alfresco

I work with alfresco 4.2

I want to get an image from alfresco through URL using uid

I can get the result through this link

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/98996554-212 f-4846-876a-89b40999901a/test.jpg
```

my problem is to do the same thing but for a pdf file

with chrome **I can not open the file**

and firefox the file is opened in **binary format**

is there a way to open a pdf file through URL using the uid of alfresco file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try using the download servlet. I believe the url you are using is not setting the mimetype headers correctly. This url should do the trick:

/alfresco/download/direct/workspace/SpacesStore/0000-0000-0000-0000/myfile.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason could be mimetype of your pdf file is not correctly set. Normally browsers have addons avilable out of box which enable them to read pdf file correctly. 
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html

Those appliation are associated with perticular file types so whenever it detects that file type browser invoke that application to deal with it. So you can make sure your file's extension and mimetype are correct.

[image]
One more thing you can try is download that file and try to open it directly in browser.

Also, there are chances file may be corrupt. Are you able to see prview of pdf in alfresco?